# How to change the theme in flutter using darkTheme:

Tags: flutter, themes

To manage themes in my MaterialApp(), i use :

```dart
MaterialApp(
  ...
  theme: isDarkTheme ? darkTheme() : lightTheme(),
)
```

`darkTheme()` and `lightTheme()` are just simple function that return `ThemeData()`

So, I use an inherited Widget to change the variable `isDarkTheme` and then i use the `setState((){})` method and all the application is rebuild

But, I saw on the Flutter documentation that we can use `darkTheme:`.

I'm trying to do this :

```dart
MaterialApp(
  ...
  theme: lightTheme(),
  darkTheme: darkTheme()
)
```

And we can change the theme during the course of the application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`darkTheme` property is used to define a `Theme` to be used when the device enters Dark mode, So you can't force your app to use `darkTheme` property because it depends on the value of `MediaQueryData.platformBrightness` which is a read-only field.

You can rather define several Themes to be used as a value for `Theme` property, and switching between them during the app course by using a `StreamBuilder` wrapped around your `MaterialApp`,which won't cause the app to stop and rebuild like the case when you were using `setState` to change theme (you'll need [rxdart](https://pub.dev/packages/rxdart) package to apply the below solution):

```
   //BehaviorSubject stream any changes immediately without explicit call
   var themeSubject = BehaviorSubject<ThemeData>();

   //This way the app won't rebuild when the user selects the same theme
   Stream<ThemeData> getTheme() => themeSubject.stream.distinct(); 

   void setTheme (MaterialColor color){
       pointsSubject.sink.add(ThemeData(primarySwatch: color) ;
   }


   return StreamBuilder<ThemeData>(
             stream: getTheme(),
             initialData: ThemeData(
                primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
                primaryTextTheme: TextTheme(
                  title: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                ),
             builder: (context, themeSnapshot){
                 return MaterialApp(theme: themeSnapshot.data);
             }
          ):
```

Then use your `InheritedWidget` to access `setTheme` and change it as you please.